# Relative extrema and absolute extrema with only one relative extrema in the function

Tags: calculus

If a relative maximum is the only relative extrema for it's function, and the function is continuous, can it be guaranteed to be the absolute maximum of the function? And a relative minimum which is the only relative extrema would be the absolute minimum? If so, is there any law that states this?

Comment: Look at the graph of $f(x)=x^2(x-1)$

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales did you mean $f(x) = (x^2)(x-1)$? Or $f(x) = x^(2(x-1))$?

Comment: The expressions $f(x)=x^2(x-1)$ and $f(x)=(x^2)(x-1)$ are equivalent.

Comment: There are 2 relative extrema for the function $f(x) = x^2(x-1)$

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question as "If a relative maximum is the only relative **maximum** $\cdots$".

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales yes, I had accidentally worded the question like that, but I made an edit to fix it. Thank you for your input though!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to specify continuity, otherwise there are counter-examples.

$$f(x)=\frac{|x|(x-1)}{x^3}$$

[image: Local, non-global maximum with only one extremum]